# How can I wrap two rows of Elements in the same manner?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have multiple rows with the same amount of Elements.

The goal is the following: if the n-th element of any line breaks to a new line, the n-th element of every other row should break too.

E.g. I've two rows with each three elements:

```
                                                                                     |<- End of Screen
<Element 1.1> <Element 1.2> <Element 1.3>                                            |
                                                                                     |
<Element 2.1> <Element 2.2> <Element 2.3 with looooooooooooooooooooooooong content>  |
                                                                                     |
```

If I narrow the screen the it should look like the following:

```
                                                         |<- End of Screen
<Element 1.1> <Element 1.2>                              |
<Element 1.3>                                            |
                                                         |
<Element 2.1> <Element 2.2>                              |
<Element 2.3 with looooooooooooooooooooooooong content>  |
                                                         |
```